# What is the benefit of && on a lambda-expression?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I'm seeing code that looks like this:

```
template<class Function>
void MyFunc(Function&& function) { function(...); }
```

What's the advantage of `&&` here, as opposed to just copying the function by value? For reference, I'm using C++14.

Comment: Do you know about [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)?

Comment: Where is the lambda in your code?

Comment: didnt find a dupe, but this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819058/is-this-a-forwarding-reference

Comment: Do you know about [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/perfect-forwarding-whats-it-all-about)?

Comment: This is a function template. It is not a lambda expression. Though, from the name of the identifiers, you might be using `MyFunc` by providing it with a lambda expression. If this is the case, the question does not make this clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem comes from avoiding copies.

Imagine this:

```
auto lambda = [ptr = std::make_unique<int>(0)]() mutable {
    std::cout << *ptr;
    ptr = std::make_unique<int>(*ptr + 1); // why not?
};

MyFunc(lambda);                     // use it normally
MyFunc([]{ std::cout << " end"; }); // use by using a temporary lambda
lambda()                            // just call the function after that
```

If the signature is `MyFunc(Function f)`, it would require a `std::move` and the lambda would not be useable after the call.

If the signature is `MyFunc(Function const& f)`, it would not work since the lambda is mutable.

If it was `MyFunc(Function& f)` then the temporary would not work.

You're basically left with `MyFunc(Function&& f)`.

---

The real question however is "Do I need to support all these cases?"

I would tell: most of the time no. Most of the time, receiving the lambda by value is the simplest and support almost every cases. This is the way the STL went.

Why? Because perfect forwarding of function objects is really hard to get perfect, and you cannot call the function multiple times in most of the cases in a pefectly generic way. I would perfect forward a function only if I want to wrap it, want to completely avoid copies and I expect function objects that are ref qualified to temporaries.