# C++ iterator argument in abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want to have an abstract class with a read and write method like:

```
template<typename Iterator>
virtual void read(uint64_t adr, Iterator begin, Iterator end) const = 0;    

template<typename Iterator>
virtual void write(uint64_t adr, Iterator begin, Iterator end) const = 0;
```

is there a way to achieve something like that?

Since there can't be a virtual template method, I thought about

1. Get rid of the abstract class and use a template instead.
   In the template I would assume there is a read/write method taking an iterator.
2. Make the abstract class a template too and pass the iterator type.

Is one of these ways a clean one?
I'm on C++11 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is one of these ways a clean one?

Yes: use static polymorphism instead of `virtual` functions. When a type is passed via a template, it is not erased and therefore needs no pre-generated virtual tables, so you can cause further template instantiation - that's what your use-case begs for.

### Solution 1 (recommended)

So, if your abstract class is used as just an "`interface`", get rid of it and write `read`/`write` in the "implementations" directly:

```
struct Impl {
  template<typename Iterator> void  read(uint64_t, Iterator, Iterator) const { /* work */ }
  template<typename Iterator> void write(uint64_t, Iterator, Iterator) const { /* work */ }
};
```

and replace usages of your implementation classes through that abstract class with

```
template<typename Impl> void use_any_impl(Impl&&) { /* work */ }
```

However, if your abstract class contains some logic/data which is meant to be inherited, you can keep the class but get rid of anything `virtual`:

```
class Abstract {
protected: ~Abstract() = default;
public:    constexpr int inherit_me() const { return 42; }
};

class Impl: public Abstract { /* read() and write() same as above */ };

/* use_any_impl() same as above */
```

### Solution 2

If your `template`d `Iterator`s always (or can be reduced to) lead to a raw array storage (e.g. one provided by `std::vector<unsigned char>::data`), which seems reasonable for raw read/write operations, you can just use raw pointers:

```
virtual void  read(uint64_t, unsigned char*, unsigned char*) const = 0;
virtual void write(uint64_t, unsigned char*, unsigned char*) const = 0;
```

Comment: instead of `template<typename Impl> void use_any_impl(Impl&&) { /* work */ }` could I use something like `template<typename Impl> void use_any_impl(std::unique_ptr<Impl>&&) { /* work */ }`

Comment: @yannick818 if you mean to pass the ownership of an `Impl` (held by a `unique_ptr`) to `use_any_impl`, accepting `std::unique_ptr<Impl>` (`&&` not needed) is your solution. If you just lend it to use during the function call, stay with `Impl&&` and call the function like `use_any_impl(*unique)`.

Comment: @yannick818 note that if your `unique_ptr` appeared with the abstract class solution to allow something like `auto unique_impl = std::make_unique<Impl>(); Abstract* p = unique_impl.get()`, it isn't needed any more with Solution 1. Simple `Impl impl` does the job. EDIT FOR THE PREVIOUS COMMENT: for clarification about `&&` (rvalue reference VS forwarding reference), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819058/is-this-a-forwarding-reference.